# Azure DevOps API Add public key

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I would like to be able to add a public key for SSH access to Azure DevOps via the API but I can't seem to find a way to do it in the doco.  Doing it manually via the UI is not feasible since this is for many users and many projects.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API is not documented, however we can track it with tools... 
You can add SSH public keys by calling below REST API:

Write a script to create the SSH keys with the `ssh-keygen` command for users, please see [Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts) for details.

Then call the REST API to add the public keys:

```
POST https://{Account}.visualstudio.com/_details/security/keys/Edit

Content-Type: application/json

Request body:

{"Description":"Test1001","__RequestVerificationToken":"","AuthorizationId":"","Data":"ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDGZyIoG6eH9nTm/Cu2nVDa7hTNfaMWkwayghFmYTvqCkOwao2YJesGVih1fA3oR4tPsVv4+Vr8wxPCfJCboUrL9NDoH1tAMsIlkQZHqgaJwnGNWnPrnp0r2+wjLQJFPq/pPd8xKwr6QU0BxzZ4RuLDfMFz/MR1cQ2iWWKJuO/TXYrSPtY9XqsmMC8Zo4zJln40PGZt+ecOyQCNHCXsEJ3C+QIUXSqAkb8yknZ4apLf1oqfFRngtV4w84Ua/ZLpNduPZrBcm/mCU5Jq6H37jxhx4kluheJrfpAXbvbQlPTKa2zaOHp7wb3B2E2HvESJmx5ExNuAHoygcq/QGjsRsiUR andy@xxx@ws0068"}
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? The only thing I can get a 401 with is Basic Auth. All other types of authentication throw a 500.

Comment: @andy-li-msft Does this POST method still work?  I receive a 400 Bad Request response from the server when attempting this using the exact same method you posted above.  I can list keys absolutely fine.

Comment: Hey, I'm developing an app that needs to clone the project from azure devops and in order to do so, I really need this endpoint to work. Are there any plans to support this?

Comment: I also see a 400 with  "Could not add public key".  I do not believe this API is supported and/or is disabled