# Add SSH key to Azure DevOps Server group or project?

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops, bamboo

According to [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#step-2--add-the-public-key-to-azure-devops-servicestfs), adding an SSH key to Azure DevOps Server ties the key to a specific user account.

Is there a way to associate the key either with a group or with a specific project, and *not* to a specific user?

We have a build pipeline set up where we use the Bamboo service hook to trigger a Bamboo build when code is merged into specific branches.  The Bamboo server then authenticates with the Azure DevOps Server, pulls the source code, and does it's stuff.

That process is broken right now because the Bamboo server is no longer authenticating with ADOS, and I'm assuming it's most likely because the primary developer for that project has left, and his account is now disabled, and he probably installed the SSH key under his account, so the Bamboo server was essentially authenticating as him.

I could create a new key pair and set everything up so that the Bamboo server would be impersonating *me*, but that leaves the same problem - what happens if for some reason my account gets disabled and no longer has access to the project?

So we would like to somehow associate the SSH key either with a group that will always have access to the project, or to the project itself.

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52658534/988264) that seems to be asking how to do something very similar (use one SSH key to allow access to multiple people / projects), but it is about Azure DevOps *in Azure*, so I'm unsure if it applies to ADOS on-prem, and also the screen shot at the end that shows the SSH key installed is still showing under "User Settings", so is it still associated with a specific user?  Or will it show up for all users?

Comment: Why not make a "bot" user, those login credentials could be stored in your group's password manager?

Answer (score -1):

The method to add public key to azuredevops in the thread you mentioned is obsolete. I tried and it seems that it is not allowed to add public key in that way. But you can try manually adding the these keys.

You can also use `ssh-copy-id`, xx.xx is the server's IP address.

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa_xxx.pub user@xx.xx
```

Or you can manually edit `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server to add multiple keys just by copying and pasting the keys.

Check [here](https://clubmate.fi/how-to-setup-and-manage-multiple-ssh-keys/) for detailed steps

Comment: This reply are not related with the question itself.