# Add SSH key to Azure DevOps pipeline user via DevOps Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, powershell-core

I want to add a SSH Public key to the Azure DevOps account running my yaml pipeline. According to this post: [Azure DevOps API Add public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658534/azure-devops-api-add-public-key) it has been possible at some point to upload the public key when authenticating with a PAT token.

I can access Azure DevOps Rest API from my pipeline and list repos etc via the Rest API, but I cannot figure out, how to build the body for the query for uploading the public SSH key. So far I have this:

```bsh
$uri = 'https://dev.azure.com/{MyOrg}/_usersSettings/keys'
$Headers = @{Authorization='Basic <encoded PAT>';'content-type'='application/json'}
$Body = @{
    displayName = 'MyKey'
    publicData = 'My Public Key starting with ssh-rsa '
    scope = 'app_token'
    isPublic = $true
    } | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $Headers -Method POST -Body $body
```

The above command produces no error as such, just a long html.

Hints on how to upload the certificate to Azure DevOps by PowerShell or any other commandline option are very welcome.

UPDATE:

I tried extracting the Authentication Id off a post in the portal as described by Hugh Lin - MSFT:
[image: Portal upload of new SSH Public Key]

Then I extracted the Authorization Id and added that to the payload of a new post. Before posting I also changed the displayName and the Public data, making the body look like this:

```
{
"contributionIds": ["ms.vss-token-web.personal-access-token-issue-session-token-provider"],
"dataProviderContext": {"properties": {
    "displayName": "AutoKey",
    "authorizationId": "48bef66f-798e-499b-94cc-720e48296bf7",
    "publicData": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDZA//Y+7vLd+P2F4WmIHpBPEMn/lPHPXrxHEJhhtnrNNZzgwIkWpgGQcuGQt2rmxEWYsSEV+CxTZcO7jig0yr8rsntUZJnCc86SVP22AfvE1rmRM/k+m6QRCBrSoHCAR+2ho/XoJ8iuZdvIV7qvV0Vk/N9rnf+KsJlK97RQWSc61rPl+7cUeXkBB8qsWOMeVxe9NhWH8DeWV+JG0nroTaZDrTq9BI5UDc7kqrRgwPCvqwT749C3k3cijxqEvK5bwWZ5NFaGj4CW8qRGXR5Sf6GJlQLgOrH+V2R7Ns5kLunD/Yy6RvSUiwokCyb3tDqBgB3W9lEtuxqcaYUwig0/GIF axel@me.com",       
    "scope": "app_token",
    "targetAccounts": ["67ebc765-c850-4d22-b95f-1d3553xxxxxx"],
    "isPublic": true,
    "sourcePage": {
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/cloudeonwest/_usersSettings/keys",
        "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.user-admin-hub-route",
        "routeValues": {
            "adminPivot": "keys",
            "controller": "ContributedPage",
            "action": "Execute",
            "serviceHost": "67ebc765-c850-4d22-b95f-1d3553bxxxxxx (Org)"
        }
    }
}}
}
```

Running the request resulted in the displayName being updated, but the publicData remained the same:

```
$answer.dataProviders.'ms.vss-token-web.personal-access-token-issue-session-token-provider'

clientId            : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
accessId            : 52447de9-8c41-4d5b-bfdb-48b4eaxxxxxx
authorizationId     : 48bef66f-798e-499b-94cc-720e48296bf7
hostAuthorizationId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
userId              : 357d38ad-6712-69e1-adc3-be8caxxxxxx
validFrom           : 7/25/2020 3:26:51 PM
validTo             : 7/25/2025 3:26:51 PM
displayName         : AutoKey
scope               : app_token
targetAccounts      : {67ebc765-c850-4d22-b95f-1d3553xxxxxx}
token               :
alternateToken      :
isValid             : True
isPublic            : True
publicData          : BBBAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDZA//Y+7vLd+P2F4WmIHpBPEMn/lPHPXrxHEJhhtnrNNZzgwIkWpgGQcuGQt2rmxEWYsSEV+CxTZcO7jig0yr8rsntUZJnCc86SVP22AfvE1rmRM/k+m6QRCBrSoHCAR+2ho/XoJ8iuZdvIV7qvV0Vk/N9rnf+KsJlK97RQWSc61rPl+7cUeXkBB8qsWOMeVxe9NhWH8DeWV+JG0nroTaZDrTq9BI5UDc7kqrRgwPCvqwT749C3k3cijxqEvK5bwWZ5NFaGj4CW8qRGXR5Sf6GJlQLgOrH+V2R7Ns5kLunD/Yy6RvSUiwokCyb3tDqBgB3W9lEtuxqcaYUwig0/GIF
source              :
claims              :
```

And the portal was clearly updated as well:
[image]

Comment: In the previous test, I only noticed that the name was successfully replaced, but did not notice whether the Key Data was replaced. After testing, I can reproduce your problem, and the Key Data cannot be replaced. So I think Azure Devops currently should not support  using rest api to upload ssh key.

Comment: It will be more convenient to add the ssh key through the UI. I updated the answer and submitted a feature request for you.  Sorry for wrong guiding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that currently azure devops does not support uploading ssh keys through rest api. The official document also does not provide a rest api that can realize this function. At present, we can only add public ssh key through the UI

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1126491/upload-public-ssh-key-to-user-setting-through-rest.html) in DC forum. You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there.The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. I really want to upload a ssh key to the pipeline account, so it can authenticate with Terraform.We are heavy users of modules that are kept in separate repos in Azure DevOps. Unfortunately, source on the modules only support ssh. We need a licensed account just to have a ssh key for this.

Comment: The voting above is for visualstudio.com. [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21&q=SSH+API) are a query for "Azure DevOps", please upvote there!